# Create Proxy in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I created a proxy with the nestjs.

All requisitions pass normally. Except for POST requests.

Look at my code:

```
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http';
import { HttpUtils } from './../utils/http.utils';
import { Controller, Param, Req, Res, All } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Config } from './../system/config';
import { ServerResponse } from 'http';
import * as http from 'http';
import { CouchDB, Log } from 'system';
import { UsuarioModel } from 'model';

@Controller('__api-proxy')
export class ApiProxyController {

    @All('*')
    root(@Param() param, @Req() c_req: IncomingMessage, @Res() c_res: ServerResponse): any {

        // habilito o cors
        HttpUtils.enableCors(c_req, c_res);

        const urlDetail = HttpUtils.getUrlDetail(Config.getConfig().endpoints.webapi);

        // modifico para o hostname em que eu estou fazendo o proxy
        c_req.headers.host = urlDetail.hostname;

        // faço o proxy
        var proxy = http.request({
            hostname: urlDetail.hostname,
            port: urlDetail.port,
            method: c_req.method,
            headers: c_req.headers,
            path: '/' + param[0],
        }, (res) => {
            res.pause();
            res.headers.Server = `Sync Server ${Config.getConfig().package.version}`;

            if (Config.getConfig().endpoints.log) {
                Log.print('[ api ] [' + c_req.connection.remoteAddress + ']     : ' + c_req.method + ' ' + res.statusCode + ' ' + c_req.url);
            }

            c_res.writeHead(res.statusCode, res.headers);
            res.pipe(c_res, {end: true});
            res.resume();
        });

        c_req.pipe(proxy, {end: true});
    }
}
```

> NodeJS error

```
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:331:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Before it worked normally, after I put the proxy under NestJS only GET and OPTIONS requests work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem:

In main.ts right after my `const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);` I have added the following lines:

```
app.use('__bank-agency-gateway', proxy(config.endpoints.bankAgencyGateway));
app.use('__bank-account', proxy(config.endpoints.bankAcountCenter));
app.use('__bank-safebox', proxy(config.endpoints.bankSafebox));
app.use('__visa-proxy', proxy(config.endpoints.visaProxy));
```

And I used the `express-http-proxy` proxy library ie the requests that are not directed to my proxys NestJS can act.

Thank you